# how to truncate file by number of characters in a specific column

Tags: python, regex, bash, awk, sed

I have 4 columns , separated by a `;`.

Some lines in the 3rd or the 4th column, are huge with more than 10000 characters.

How would you remove the lines , regardless of which columns , where the length of one specific column goes beyond 10000 characters?

I tried with that

```
awk '{i += (length() + 1); if (i <= 10000) print $ALL}'
```

But it is taking the whole file and not only specific column and I want the length of the column, regardless if it is the 3rd or the 4th or maybe both.

TIA

Comment: You want to remove the entire line if the length of either column three or four is longer than 10000 characters?

Comment: Hi Etan, the entire line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F ';' 'length($3)<10000 && length($4)<10000' file
```

This will print only those line that have length of field 3 and 4 less than 10000. So in other words if any of those columns have length>=10000 then those lines will not be printed in output.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. It was more of a `OR` , I was thinking so `awk -F ';' 'length($3)<10000 || length($4)<10000' file`

Comment: But you wrote `How would you remove the lines , regardless of which columns , where the length of one specific column goes beyond 10000 characters?`

Comment: I was thinking like that : If column 3 > 10000 characters, bye but if column 4 > 10000 characters, also bye. Is it what you understood?

Comment: A little boolean logic applies here. If we call the condition `length($3) >= 10000` `A` for brevity, and similarly `B` for the condition on `$4`. Then the condition for when you want to remove a line is `A || B`. The condition for keeping the line, which is what `awk` wants, then is `! (A || B)`, which, by DeMorgan's law, is equivalent to `!A && !B`. That's exactly what the condition @anubhava provides above represents...

Comment: Thanks @twalberg: That's what I tried to explain in simple words below my answer but your boolean logic makes it crystal clear.

Comment: Ok, guys. My bad. I guess it was clear for me, in my thoughts. Thanks for the explanation , it is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

All you need is:

```
$ cat file
a;b;c
d;efg;h
i;j;klm
opqr;s;t
uv;wx;yz

$ egrep -v '[^;]{3}' file
a;b;c
uv;wx;yz

$ awk '!/[^;]{3}/' file
a;b;c
uv;wx;yz

$ sed -r '/[^;]{3}/d' file
a;b;c
uv;wx;yz
```

Change the "3" to 1001 or whatever...

Comment: Minor nitpick - `egrep` is [deprecated](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) but ++ for simplicity none the less.

Answer (score 4):

Through sed,

```
sed '/^[^;]*;[^;]*;\([^;]\{10001\}[^;]*;[^;]*|[^;]*;[^;]\{10001\}[^;]*\)$/d' file
```

Through python,

```
import csv
with open('/path/to/input/file') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        if len(row[2]) <= 10000 and len(row[3]) <= 10000:
            print(row)
```

Comment: for the sed i guess `.\{10001\}` does not work, you need a `[^;]\{10001\}`, due to possible separator taken and it should not

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
sed -n '/[^;]\{10001\}/!p' input
```

or this:

```
sed '/[^;]\{10001\}/d' input
```

Comment: You beat me to it by a few seconds, have an upvote! I know this answers OP's question, but I would have used this : `sed '/\(^\|;\)[^;]\{10001\}/d' input` as a more general answer (works for the first column also).

Comment: You are right, mea culpa. I really need another coffee.